# Is there any way to run TOAD on 64bit Oracle Client?

Tags: oracle11g, windows-7-x64, toad

I am using Toad for Oracle Xpert 10.1.1.8 on Win 7 64bit operating system. I have installed Oracle 11g 64bit client. I am getting this error: **Cannot load OCI DLL: C:\oracle\product\11.1.0\oci.dll**. I googled this error and found TOAD only runs on 32bit Oracle Client. Is there any way to run TOAD on 64bit Oracle Client?

Comment: Where have you installed Toad, as in what directory?

Comment: @Incognito here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle 10\Toad.exe"

Comment: Can you try installing it in a different location and not install it under Program Files (x86). Once you do that, try running toad again

Comment: @Incognito I found it. Toad For Oracle 11.6 and above versions supports 64bit Oracle client.

Comment: Yes, 11.6 onward support 64bit clients

Comment: @Incognito Write an answer to this question and I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [knowledge article](https://support.quest.com/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL33534) on Quest Support base

> Toad for Oracle versions prior to 11.6 cannot support a 64-bit Oracle
>   Client due to limitations in Delphi programming language used in some
>   of Toads components.
>
> Versions 11.6 onwards are fully 64-bit compliant. There is now a
>   64-bit installer and 32-bit installer. Please note that you should
>   install a 64-bit Oracle client for the 64-bit Toad installation and a
>   32-bit Oracle Client for the 32-bit installation.
>
> For 11.5 and below, a 32-bit Oracle client must be installed